# Android - new column in database and restore DB from backup

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In Android I am using SQLite database and has a structure with ID, name, age.

The users have an ability to backup the database to Google Drive. Untill now everything is OK.

The problem is, I am developing a new version of my app and I am adding another column to the database. So it will look like ID, name, age, gender.

I solved this with `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1)`, so if the version of DB is older as the current, it will run onUpgrade, when I add that new column via ALTER table.

So far so good. But what if the user has this new database already, but on Google drive has the old one and he restores that old database from cloud?

Will the onUpgrade run immediately when the db file is replaced with older version, or do I need to force to run onUpgrade after every restore from cloud?

Not sure when the onUpgrade is executed - only on the app start, or anytime when any DB operation is called and it sees the difference in versions?

Comment: Version is readed from database.. So this should be no problem... All you need to do is to use new instance of helper class (as AFAIK onUpgrade is called when there is no opened connection to db and you are trying obtain one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the onUpgrade run immediately when the db file is replaced with
> older version...

No, `onUpgrade()` is not invoked after the db is replaced.

> do I need to force to run onUpgrade after every restore from cloud?

You should not call `onUpgrade()`.

After the restore process is finished, you can call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` which will open the database.
At this point the difference of the versions of the existing database and your code in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class will invoke `onUpgrade()`.

Comment: thank you, I think it is enough, when the onUpgrade will be called if the user does some action which will open and work with DB, so then onUpgrade will be called, so I don't need to call getWritableDatabase() after DB restore at all.

Comment: @Darksymphony the database opens with getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: yes, but I have getWritableDatabase() in DatabaseHelper class and it is executed when I retrieve data from DB, I wanted to say, I don't need to call getWritableDatabase() directly after restoring the data from cloud, because it is called, when the user does some action, which is connecting to DB, so then onUpgrade will be called in that time and not immediately after restore, and that's ok I think

Comment: @Darksymphony if this is what you mean then yes. But sometimes the upgrade operation may take a while, so if you leave it to be executed when the user decides to access the db, they may experience some delay. On the other hand if you do it after the restore operation, it will be just part of the whole process.